# Refactoring options in Visual Studio 2010 differ between C# and VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

In VS2010 C#, when I right-click there is "Refactor" menu with following options:

- Rename
- Extract Method
- Encapsulate Field
- Extract Interface
- Remove Parameters
- Reorder Parameters

Are these options available in VS2010 VB.Net? All I can see is "Rename" when I right click?

Comment: Are you using express editions? Because these versions are limited, that could be why you can't se these options

Comment: I am using Professional Edition in both computers.

Comment: Unfortunately the IDE features for the different languages aren't quite the same, often lacking in the other languages.  VB just doesn't have the same refactoring features as C# does.  There's also a good amount of other things that VB has that C# doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Rename" is the only refactoring VB.Net has. C# is definitely more robust.

Check out [Code Rush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/). It's a slimmed down, free version of their full tool but it may provide some of your missing refactorings.

Personally, I use and absolutely love [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Well worth the money IMO.

Comment: I used Resharper a lot in the past, but don't quite like it - need to pay, seems to decrease VS performance, etc. Will check out Code Rush Express. Are you sure though that VB.Net definitely only has "Rename"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure VB.Net only has "Rename". Check out this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530714/visual-studio-refactor-for-vb-net) and this question (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/aee7db8f-3b3e-40cf-81fa-543228c96044/)

Comment: I agree, ReSharper can be a resource hog. Version 6 has some performance issues, so I'm still on version 5 right now. However, ReSharper is so good, it's worth buying more RAM if that's what's necessary. I work in a very large VS solution and am crippled when I don't have ReSharper. Kinda like trying to work without intellisense.

Comment: Yeah thats another thing with Resharper, once you are used to it, you cannot live without it - and the fact that it needs more memory, and pay for it - some company just don't want to spend. So yeah Code Rush Xpress seems like the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Just one more comment on ReSharper and I'll let it go :) I *easily* pay for the cost of ReSharper and 4 gigs of memory in two weeks with how much more productive I am with it.

Comment: I agree with your point, but when you work in a company that choice to spend and the justification not just belong to you. Plus usually a company likes to standardise their working environment - so I might have to force everyone else to use Resharper (and thus purchase license and upgrade memory). So far I have no need for that since I am pretty happy with the default VS2010 C# refactoring.