# 'Extract Interface' in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, refactoring, visual-studio-2005

Is there way to use the `Extract Interface` refactor option when in `VB.NET`?

I've noticed that `Refactor` does not show in the right-click context menu when in VB.NET.

Comment: Nope, MS didn't include it.  See [This post][1] for options.  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761943/refactoring-options-in-visual-studio-2010-differ-between-c-sharp-and-vb

Answer (score 2):

Since VS 2005 Microsoft has had a deal with DevExpress to offer free refactoring tools for Visual Basic. For VS 2005/2008 look for Refactor!, for newer versions try CodeRush Express.

Comment: And now it's no longer available.  They only offer CodeRush, for $250.

Comment: That's too bad. It was the free versions that got me to subscribe in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.net 2015, use `Edit` > `Refactor` > `Extract Interface`. This functionality has been added.