# Visual Studio 2012 Shortcut for Rename.Refactor for Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, refactoring, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to use a keyboard shortcut for the rename refactor feature for visual basic. When I try

```
Rename.Refactor
```

In the command window it tells me the command is not available. Perhapps this shortcut is C# only?

Comment: There's more info about the refactoring difference in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761943/refactoring-options-in-visual-studio-2010-differ-between-c-sharp-and-vb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Refactor.Rename** works only in C#, don't know why. But you can bind keyboard shortcut to **EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.Rename** - that one works for vb.
(*CTRL+M, CTRL+R* is free)