# Can VB extract interfaces from a class like C#?

Tags: vb.net

We have a large chunk of legacy code in VB that I want to unit test, so step one if building interfaces.  In C#, visual studio has the cool little Refactor -> Extract Interface function.  VB Doesn't, though?

Is there a good way to do this in VB?

Comment: The extract interface function is available in Visual Studio, for both C# and VB.Net

Comment: @Jay Refactoring in VB is limited: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7761943/573218

Comment: This is not the most efficient solution, but you could convert the legacy code to C#, extract to interfaces and then convert it back to VB.NET. Check out [Convert VB.NET to C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) for a free online converter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Extract Interface function. VB Doesn't, though?

Yes. Unfortunately, Microsoft Visual Studio does not support refactor functionality for VB.NET.

You can install third party tools such as ReSharper, though.

For more information, also have a look at this question on SO: [Refactoring options in Visual Studio 2010 differ between C# and VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761943/refactoring-options-in-visual-studio-2010-differ-between-c-sharp-and-vb)